# Перебор ключей словаря с разными параметрами

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть словарь.Там более 200 ключей. Кидаю Постом получаю 200.Собираю все ключи в all_keys, меняю у одного ключа значение,например 'amount' на None,делаю запрос и получаю статус. Задача:По очереди каждому ключу подставлять None, отправлять запрос и получать статус. Функция нужна, но вот что-то никак не допру. Помогите

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://......'

questionnaire = {
  "appType":"credit",
  "step":"FULL",
  "data":{
    "amount":50000,
    "period":36,
    "loanPurpose":"ConstructionHouseroom",
    "loanPurposeDescription":"",
    "phoneNumber":"+77777777777",
    "email":"",
  }
}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(questionnaire), headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
questionnaire['data']['amount'] = None
print(questionnaire)

i = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(questionnaire), headers=headers)
chench_field = i.status_code
print(chench_field)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот. Решил таки. Может кому понадобится:

```
for key in questionnaire["data"]:
    tmp = questionnaire["data"][key]
    questionnaire["data"][key] = None
    print(key)
    print(questionnaire["data"][key])

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(questionnaire), headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    questionnaire["data"][key] = tmp
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь со справкой по оформлению: [Код и предварительно отформатированный текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).